# scapy - fields_desc - add field as offset

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I'm trying to describe a field as an offset and access it's data

For example:

```
fields_desc = [LEShortField("structure_size",0),
               ByteField("flags",0),
               **LEShortField("blob_offset",0)**,
               LEFieldLenField("user_name_length", 0),
               LEShortField("user_name_maxlength", 0),
               **LEIntField("user_name_offset", 0)**]
```

I need to take the variable blob_offset and add it user_name_offset in order to extract the user name.

How can I do it ?? I didn't find and special variable for it...

Thanks

Comment: what do you want your packet to look like in the end? do you want `user_name` to also be a field? do you plan on parsing the entire "blob"?

Comment: yes. I need the user_name as a field.  I just don't know where to insert it because it depends on a specific offset...Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

well you don't exactly say how your packet looks, assuming your "blob" and username are right after the packet you already specified you can try to do something like this:

```
fields_desc = [LEShortField("structure_size",0),
               ByteField("flags",0),
               LEFieldLenField("blob_offset",0, length_of="blob_offset_pad", fmt="!H"),
               LEFieldLenField("user_name_length", 0, length_of="user_name"),
               LEShortField("user_name_maxlength", 0),
               LEFieldLenField("user_name_offset", 0, length_of="user_name", fmt="!I"),
               StrFixedLenField("blob_offset_pad", 0, length_from = lambda pkt: pkt.blob_offset),
               StrFixedLenField("user_name_offset_pad", 0, length_from = lambda pkt: pkt.user_name_offset),
               StrFixedLenField("user_name", "", length_from= lambda pkt: pkt.user_name_length)]
```

again can't really test this because you didn't provide any useful examples